# Show that $\exists \delta >0$ s.t $|f(z)|>\delta \; \forall z\in \partial B(z_0,\varepsilon )$.

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, compactness

> Let $\Omega $ be a domain and let $f:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be
> a non-constant holomorphic function. Suppose that $z_0 \in \Omega$ is
> a zero of multiplicity $m$ of $f$.
>
> Let $\varepsilon>0$ be s.t $\overline{B(z_0,\varepsilon )}\subset
>  \Omega $ and $|f(z)|\neq 0\; \; \forall z\in \partial
>  B(z_0,\varepsilon )$.
>
> Show that $\exists \delta >0$ s.t $|f(z)|>\delta \; \; \forall z\in
>  \partial B(z_0,\varepsilon )$.

I would like to prove this by showing contradiction.

Proof Begin.

Assume that $\forall \delta >0$ we have $|f(z)|\leq \delta $ for some $z \in \partial B(z_0,\varepsilon )$.

Let $ \delta = \frac{1}{n}$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Then by assumption, $\exists z_n\in \partial B(z_0,\varepsilon )$  s.t $|f(z_n)|\leq \frac{1}{n} $ for every $n$.

But, as $\partial B(z_0,\varepsilon )$ closed and bounded,  $\partial B(z_0,\varepsilon )$ is compact.

This implies that, the sequence $\{z_n \}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ has a subsequence $\{w_n \}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ that converges to $w \in \partial B(z_0,\varepsilon )$.

Recall that as $f$ is continuous on a compact set $\partial B(z_0,\varepsilon )$, $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\partial B(z_0,\varepsilon )$.

Now, observe that as $n\rightarrow \infty$, $\frac{1}{n}\rightarrow 0$.

$\Rightarrow |f(w_n)|\rightarrow |f(w)|\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{1}{n}\Leftrightarrow f(w)=0$

This is a contradiction, thus the statement is true. $\blacksquare $

Is this valid proof?

Moreover, I wonder if the uniform continuity can be omitted here and just replaced by a normal continuity.

Comment: Why don't you consider $1/f$?

Comment: It looks like the right idea, but this statement I have problems with: "But, as there are finitely many subcovering of ... ". There's no reason why that should be true, and it does not imply compactness either. You can just say the boundary of a disk is always compact.

Comment: @AmejiB. Oh, you're right. I should've said that the boundary of a disk is closed and bounded. But, what do you think about the uniform continuity?

Comment: I don't think that is needed here. Continuity is enough to say that $f(w_n)\to f(w)$. Since $|f(w_n)|\leq \frac1n$, indeed $|f(w)|=0$.